# Extracting specific pattern in file using grep or sed

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have the following file:

```
esdf http://x.com/dfsdfg&%^*
dsfdfg http://x.com/dgfhfgh
dfgdfg http://x.com/
dfgdg http://x.com/fghfgh#!
dfgdg http://x.com/fghfghfghj
rdfdre http://x.com/jkljlklkj
rdfg http://x.com/kjhjkj
rfdfg http://x.com/kjlkj
drfgdfdghttp://x.com/jklkjljkl
dfgdfgd http://x.com/jkljkl
http://x.com/jklkjl
http://x.com/jkkjljkljkl
```

I want to extract all strings start with `http://x.com/`.

What I tried is:

```
grep -o http://x.com/[a-zA-Z0-9]* file.txt
```

But the result is not what I want exactly. What should I do with special characters

## update

I don't know what I should do with special characters. You see first line is `esdf http://x.com/dfsdfg&%^*`. When I run the command output is `http://x.com/dfsdfg` But I want `http://x.com/dfsdfg&%^*` to be printed!

I want this output:

```
http://x.com/dfsdfg#$^
http://x.com/dgfhfgh#$&&*
http://x.com/
http://x.com/fghfgh
http://x.com/fghfghfghj
http://x.com/jkljlklkj
http://x.com/kjhjkj
http://x.com/kjlkj
http://x.com/jklkjljkl
http://x.com/jkljkl
http://x.com/jklkjl
http://x.com/jkkjljkljkl
```

Comment: Try `grep '^http://x.com/' file.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]` only matches the characters you have listed there.  If you want to match more characters, list more characters.

```
grep -o 'http://x\.com/[-^#!?&%$*_a-zA-Z0-9]*' file.txt
```

Because `&` and `*` have special meaning to the shell, you need to quote the regex.  (It's a good idea generally, anyway.)

Maybe even go all the way to any non-blank:

```
grep -o 'http://x\.com/[^[:blank:]]*' file.txt
```

Or, if the matching pattern always stretches through the end of line, simply

```
grep -o 'http://x\.com/.*' file.txt
```

In a character class, every character only matches itself, except the range operator `-`, the negation `^`, and the terminator `]`.  If you want to include them in the character class, you need to put them first, except the negation, which is matches itself when it is *not* the first character in the class.  The named POSIX classes `[:blank:]`, `[:alnum:]` etc. complicate the matter slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
grep -o 'http://x\.com/.*' inputfile
```

The `.*` will match all characters to the end of the line.